# Almacenar y comparar valor de atributo de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, objeto, atributos

Tengo un objeto con unos atributos y me gustaría almacenar el valor de uno (el atributo es "estado" y tiene de valor "cerrado") en una variable para comparar su valor mediante una sentencia "if". Lo que busco es hacer algo dependiendo del valor del atributo "estado".

He probado algo tal que así pero no funciona:

```
var tipo = objeto.getAttribute('estado', 'cerrado');

if (tipo == 'cerrado') {

//ejecución

} else {

//ejecución

}
```

El objeto es el siguiente:

```
// Pulsador Cerrado
var pulsador_cerrado = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.define('electrics.pulsador_cerrado', {
    size: {width: 80, height: 40},
    position: {x: 50},
    attrs: {
        '.': {magnet: false},
        '.body': {width: 50, height: 25},
        '.input': {ref: '.body', 'ref-x': -4, 'ref-y': 0.5, magnet: true, port: 'in'},
        '.output': {ref: '.body', 'ref-x': 84, 'ref-y': 0.5, magnet: true, port: 'out'},
        circle: {r: 5, stroke: 'black', fill: 'transparent', 'stroke-width': 1},
        image: {'xlink:href': 'pulsador.nc.jpg'},
        **estado: 'cerrado'**
    },
});
```

¿Sabéis como almacenar el valor de un atributo de un objeto y como poder comparar el valor de dicho atributo con otro valor?

Pd: Estoy usando librería joint y jquery.

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En pulsador_cerrado tienes una definición de clase que luego tienes que instanciar según lo que he visto en la documentación.
Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
var pulsador_cerrado = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.define('electrics.pulsador_cerrado', {
    size: {width: 80, height: 40},
    position: {x: 50},
    attrs: {
        '.': {magnet: false},
        '.body': {width: 50, height: 25},
        '.input': {ref: '.body', 'ref-x': -4, 'ref-y': 0.5, magnet: true, port: 'in'},
        '.output': {ref: '.body', 'ref-x': 84, 'ref-y': 0.5, magnet: true, port: 'out'},
        circle: {r: 5, stroke: 'black', fill: 'transparent', 'stroke-width': 1},
        image: {'xlink:href': 'pulsador.nc.jpg'},
        estado: 'cerrado'
    },
});

//En base a lo que has definido creamos un objeto
var objeto= new pulsador_cerrado();

//Con esto obtienes el valor de estado
var tipo= objeto.attributes.attrs["estado"];
```

Espero que te funcione

Comment: He comprobado lo que has puesto y funciona, la unica pregunta que tengo es por qué me salta error cuando uso la consola de internet cuando realizo el cambio de atributo? @IDanny7